# Change contextMenuStrip based on state of a different object

Tags: vb.net, contextmenustrip

I am looking for a good way to implement a TreeView in VB.net whose contextMenuStrip is variant based on the state of a different object in the form.

Specifically, in the 'TreeView' below, when the object state=1 display contextMenuStrip1 on items, and when state=2 display contextMenuStrip2 on items.

So far, I've been implementing context menus like the code below, and adding the contextMenuStrip when I create the node.

```
Dim Context1 As ContextMenuStrip = New ContextMenuStrip
AddHandler Context1.Items.Add("Delete Item").Click, AddressOf DeleteSub


------------------
| + TreeNode1
| + TreeNode2
| + TreeNode3
|   |- Item1
|   |- Item2
|   |- Item3
------------------
```

Comment: You can disable things when the menu opens depending on the thing it is over

Comment: Would it also be possible to append a number to the contextMenuStrip item?  say if i selected row 13 of a dataGridView, append the '13' to the string.  "Delete Item 13" for example?

Comment: Yes, I have a CMS that does a fill in the blank type thing - you need to set the whole text though to avoid "Delete Item 13 15 45 47 1 13..."

Comment: what is the *object* in `object state=1`?   If you dropped 2 of them onto the form, you could easily show one or the other based on whatever.  You could also have the event handlers all hooked up ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what this object is which determines the menu to use, so I used a `CheckBox`.  If the object in question is something like that, you could reassign the `ContextMenuStrip` when the state changes - in this case, using the `CheckChange` event:

```
Private Sub chkShow2_CheckedChanged(sender...
    If chkShow2.Checked Then
        tv1.ContextMenuStrip = cms2
    Else
        tv1.ContextMenuStrip = cms1
    End If
End Sub
```

If the state isnt known until the moment the menu is needed, re/assign the menu in the `MouseDown` event for the `TreeView`:

```
If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
    If chkShow2.Checked Then
        tv1.ContextMenuStrip = cms2
    Else
        tv1.ContextMenuStrip = cms1
    End If
End If
```

You can also show the menu manually, rather than assign it to the control:

```
Private Sub tv1_MouseDown(sender ...
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        If chkShow2.Checked Then
            cms2.Show(tv1, e.Location)
        Else
            cms1.Show(tv1, e.Location)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

*`Would it also be possible to append a number to the contextMenuStrip item?`*

Yes.  You can add/change or delete menu items before it shows.  For instance, if you had nodes `{A, B, C}`, and wanted to implement a `Move To...` item, when it opens over and item in node B, disable that destination.

Comment: The items in the TreeView are going to be 'steps' that the user can add to a dataGridView.  each of the steps is going to have attributes that are configurable in the dataGridView.  The position in the dataGridView, position, last step, etc, is going to determine the context menu, to insert, append, overwrite among others.

Comment: I would avoid a totally dynamic menu.  For instance, build it with all those entries (Append, Insert, Replace, Move Up, Move Down etc) then just hide or disable the ones that do not apply.

Comment: I was looking at a dynamic menu because these functions need to be run on the row in the dataGridView that the user currently has selected.  and that the context menu should show what 'step' number they were applying that operation to. but that does make sense, to change the visibility of the menus and attach the row number to the end.

Comment: By ***totally*** dynamic, I meant adding and removing items frequently.  If you need it, you need it, but I would try to have a set of menuitems that are disabled or hidden when they dont apply.  Showing the "step number" is just changing the text, it doesnt require removing or adding an item.